# Is there a way to load config file on the fly?

Tags: configuration, multiprocessing, configuration-files, openstack

I have a .conf file which I don't wish to pass via cmd line (--config-file) at process start. Instead, I want it to be loaded dynamically.

I use oslo_config library to register configuration options and I need the conf file to be parsed by the oslo_config library.

PS: As this oslo_config CONF object is already circulated in my multi process framework, I don't want to use other libraries like ConfigParser or the like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just initialize another olslo_config.cfg.ConfigOpts() instance

```
self.conf = cfg.ConfigOpts()
self.conf(
    sys.argv[1:], # if there is, can be []
    project="whatever", # but will affect the searching directories
    default_config_files=["path/to/my/conf"] # if not set, will do a auto searching
)
# use it via self.conf.example_section.example_option
```